# Videos Autoplay don't work in vue-slick-carousel

Tags: nuxt.js

Framework : NUXT SSR.

Explanation: We need to play the videos inside the carousel component. As the user will click on next/prev button of carousel or click on the video itself, the video should play and stop if clicked again on the video. We're using vue-slick-carousel library for it. The slides containing the videos should be centered and should be multiple in a single viewport.

Issue: If the videos are fewer and inside the viewport, videos are playing correctly. If the videos are more, the carousel might be adjusting the videos outside the viewport. In that case, only the video's audio is playing not the video. And it is lagging also.

We're using [vue-slick-carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-slick-carousel) library for this.
I checked an example online for this: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-sky-ts09p?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue.
We can see even in the above example if we click the indicators one after the other, the 4th video's sound is playing only not the video.
Mine have a use-case of multiple videos in a single view which we can do with slidesToShow option.

Here is the full code example:

```
<template>
<vue-slick-carousel v-bind="slickOptions">
          <div
            v-for="(item, index) in someArray"
            :key="${index}-carousel"
          >
            <video
              :src="item.src"
              playsinline
              :id="`video${index}"
              @click="(e) => changeAutoplayIndex(index, e)"
            ></video>
          </div>
        </vue-slick-carousel>
   </template>
        
   <script>
   data() {
     return {
       slickOptions: {
            initialSlide: 0,
            slidesToShow: 5,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            centerMode: true,
            arrows: false,
            infinite: true,
            swipe: false,
            autoplay: false,
          }}
     }     
   methods:{     
    changeAutoplayIndex(index, e) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          const lastAutoPlayVideo = document.querySelector('#video${this.autoplayIndex}')
          const currentVideo = document.querySelector('#video${index}')
          
          if (this.autoplayIndex !== null && this.autoplayIndex === index) {
          
            lastAutoPlayVideo.pause()
            
          } else if (this.autoplayIndex !== null) {
          
            lastAutoPlayVideo.pause()  // pausing the previous video
            currentVideo.currentTime = 0 
            currentVideo.play() // starting new video that was clicked.
            
          } else {
            currentVideo.currentTime = 0
            currentVideo.play()
          }
          this.autoplayIndex = index
        }, 200)
      }
}
```

Can anyone suggest a library with the above use-case? Or help debug this video autoplay issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your actual issue, but your code had a lot of ESlint errors with a few missing backticks mainly.

Please try the following solution

```html
<template>
  <vue-slick-carousel v-bind="slickOptions">
    <div v-for="(item, index) in someArray" :key="`${index}-carousel`">
      <video
        :id="`video${index}`"
        :src="item.src"
        playsinline
        @click="(e) => changeAutoplayIndex(index, e)"
      ></video>
    </div>
  </vue-slick-carousel>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      slickOptions: {
        initialSlide: 0,
        slidesToShow: 5,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        centerMode: true,
        arrows: false,
        infinite: true,
        swipe: false,
        autoplay: false,
      },
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeAutoplayIndex(index, e) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const lastAutoPlayVideo = document.querySelector(
          `#video${this.autoplayIndex}`
        )
        const currentVideo = document.querySelector(`#video${index}`)

        if (this.autoplayIndex !== null && this.autoplayIndex === index) {
          lastAutoPlayVideo.pause()
        } else if (this.autoplayIndex !== null) {
          lastAutoPlayVideo.pause() // pausing the previous video
          currentVideo.currentTime = 0
          currentVideo.play() // starting new video that was clicked.
        } else {
          currentVideo.currentTime = 0
          currentVideo.play()
        }
        this.autoplayIndex = index
      }, 200)
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Also, using the `index` of a `v-for` for `key` is not a idea at all, it's actually even doing the opposite.

Also, do you have a [repro] for your issue?